# @DirtiesContext is not working with Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to run some integration tests in Spring Boot. For this I believe we should use `@DirtiesContext` to clean up the database after each test has run.

I have tried several methods right now, but all of them have the same effect.

This is my setup:

- Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE
- SQL Server 2016
- Kotlin 1.2.21

This is the complete POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.brabantia.esb</groupId>
    <artifactId>log-db</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>log-db</name>
    <description>Log database application for TIBCO ESB</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.21</kotlin.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.3.0</vaadin.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.10.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <jupyter.version>5.1.0</jupyter.version>
        <surefire.version>2.19.1</surefire.version>

        <!-- Properties are prefixed with flyway. -->
        <flyway.user>esb_logging_user</flyway.user>
        <flyway.password>esb_logging_user</flyway.password>

        <!-- List are defined as comma-separated values -->
        <flyway.schemas>dbo</flyway.schemas>

        <!-- Individual placeholders are prefixed by flyway.placeholders. -->
        <!--<flyway.placeholders.keyABC>valueXYZ</flyway.placeholders.keyABC>-->
        <!--<flyway.placeholders.otherplaceholder>value123</flyway.placeholders.otherplaceholder>-->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- The package of your generated sources -->
                    <packageName>com.brabantia.esb.logdb.schema</packageName>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/schemas/BrabantiaMain.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <user>esb_logging_user</user>
                    <password>esb_logging_user</password>
                    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=esb_logging</url>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>schema1</schema>
                        <schema>schema2</schema>
                        <schema>schema3</schema>
                    </schemas>
                    <placeholders>
                        <keyABC>valueXYZ</keyABC>
                        <otherplaceholder>value123</otherplaceholder>
                    </placeholders>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

## Entities

### Log Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log")
internal data class LogEntity(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Long = -1,

        @Column(name = "descriptive_message")
        val descriptiveMessage: String = "",

        @Column(name = "message_code")
        val messageCode: String = "",

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "log", cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)])
        val references: MutableSet<LogReferenceEntity> = mutableSetOf(),

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "log", cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)])
        val messageContent: LogMessageContentEntity? = null
)
```

### LogReference Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log_reference")
internal class LogReferenceEntity(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Long? = null,

        @Column(name = "name")
        val Name: String = "",

        @Column(name = "value")
        val value: String = "",

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "log_id")
        var log: LogEntity? = null)
```

### LogMessageContent Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log_message_content")
internal data class LogMessageContentEntity(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Long? = null,

        @Column(name = "message_content")
        val messageContent: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(),

        @Column(name = "create_date_time")
        val createDateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),

        @OneToOne(cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)])
        @JoinColumn(name = "log_id")
        var log: LogEntity = LogEntity()
) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as LogMessageContentEntity

        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (!Arrays.equals(messageContent, other.messageContent)) return false
        if (createDateTime != other.createDateTime) return false
        if (log != other.log) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id?.hashCode() ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(messageContent)
        result = 31 * result + createDateTime.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + log.hashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```

## Repositories

The repositories are all very standard

```
@Transactional
internal interface LogRepository : CrudRepository<LogEntity, Long>

@Transactional
internal interface LogReferenceRepository : CrudRepository<LogReferenceEntity, Long>

@Transactional
internal interface LogMessageContentRepository : CrudRepository<LogMessageContentEntity, Long>
```

## Service

I only have one service for handling the Log instances, which also handles the associated LogReferenceEntity and LogMessageContentEntity objects.

```
@Service
@Transactional
internal class JpaLogService(
        val logRepository: LogRepository,
        val logReferenceRepository: LogReferenceRepository,
        val logMessageContentRepository: LogMessageContentRepository) : LogService {

    override fun retrieveLogs(): List<LogDTO> {
        return logRepository.findAll().map { it.toDTO() }
    }

    override fun retrieveLog(id: Long): LogDTO? {
        return logRepository.findOne(id)?.toDTO()
    }

    override fun addLog(logCreateDTO: LogCreateDTO): LogDTO {
        val log = LogEntity.fromDto(logCreateDTO)

        // Add a reference to each log instance, and persist to the database
        log.references.forEach {reference ->
            reference.log = log
            logReferenceRepository.save(reference)
        }

        log.messageContent?.let {
            it.log = log
            logMessageContentRepository.save(it)
        }

        return logRepository.save(log).toDTO()
    }
}
```

## Integration test

I have only added a part of the test class.

What is happening is that once a test has run that adds an instance to the database, the instance is not removed after the test has finished. In this example I have left out the `@DirtiesContext` annotation, and I will show what I tried below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
internal class JpaLogServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var service: LogService

    @Autowired
    lateinit var repository: LogRepository

    @Test
    fun `'retrieveLogs' should retrieve empty list if repository doesn't contain entities`() {
        assertThat(service.retrieveLogs()).isEmpty()
    }

    @Test
    fun `'addLog' should return the created entity`() {
        val result = service.addLog(logCreateDTO = LogCreateDTO())
        assertThat(result).isNotNull()
        assertThat(result.id).isNotNull()
    }
}
```

### `@DirtiesContext` on the class without any parameters

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
internal class JpaLogServiceTest {
    ...
}
```

### `@DirtiesContext` on the class with `classMode`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
internal class JpaLogServiceTest {
    ...
}
```

### `@DirtiesContext` on the test method that is saving the instance to the database

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
internal class JpaLogServiceTest {

    ...

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    fun `'addLog' should return the created entity`() {
        val result = service.addLog(logCreateDTO = LogCreateDTO())
        assertThat(result).isNotNull()
        assertThat(result.id).isNotNull()
    }
}
```

### `@DirtiesContext` on the test method that is saving the instance to the database with `methodMode`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
internal class JpaLogServiceTest {

    ...

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.AFTER_METHOD)
    fun `'addLog' should return the created entity`() {
        val result = service.addLog(logCreateDTO = LogCreateDTO())
        assertThat(result).isNotNull()
        assertThat(result.id).isNotNull()
    }
}
```

I also tried some other things, but I have the feeling that I am not too far off.

Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `@DirtiesContext` to clear up database changes between tests although sometimes it might be necessary if application contexts are being shared incorrectly between test classes.

Instead; you should just mark your tests as `@Transactional`. This will ensure every test method is wrapped by a Spring transaction which will be rolled back regardless of the outcome.

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    fun `'addLog' should return the created entity`() {
        val result = service.addLog(logCreateDTO = LogCreateDTO())
        assertThat(result).isNotNull()
        assertThat(result.id).isNotNull()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you. `@Transactional` fixed it